# Using user input as a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a sample webpage that asks users for an integer, and if it is between 1 and 12, it will return the corresponding day of christmas (8th day of christmas: 8 maids a milking, etc.)

I am not very experienced with javascript, but I am not aware of any other way to make the program work in html. Python is not an option, sadly. I am stuck while trying to gather a user-provided integer as a variable which the webpage then displays. My code is below. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
<!>
<html>
<head>
<title> Merry Christmas! </title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="number" id="inputfield1" name="inputfield1" />
<input type="submit" id="Submit" text="Submit" onclick="compute()" />
<script type = "text/javascript">

function compute(){
    var cday = document.getElementByName("inputfield1");
    document.write(cday);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var cday = document.getElementByName("inputfield1").value;`

Comment: You have the input element, you need its `.value` property to get what the user typed. Stick a `+` just before it (ie. before `document.`) to convert it to a number. You need an array of values, and just get the corresponding one. Easy, right?

Comment: @KevinKloet That doesn't matter, inline event handlers are only evaluated at trigger-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your page is you need to get the value of the input based off of its id.

```
var cday = document.getElementById("inputfield1").value;
```

A better solution is to add an event listener to your input. The onclick attribute isn't best practice today and event listeners are the more widely accepted solution. Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <input type="number" id="inputInteger" />
 <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" text="Submit" />
    
    <p id="result"></p>

 <script type = "text/javascript">
        // Event Listener that Runs "Compute()" on a Click
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", compute);

        // Gets Input Value and Displays it in a <p>
        function compute() {
            var day = document.getElementById("inputInteger").value;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = day;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementByName` doesn't exist. you can either use `document.getElementById("inputfield1")` or `document.getElementsByName("inputfield1")[0]`

then you will have a dom element, not the input value, you can access the value with the `value` property of the element:

```
var cday = document.getElementById("inputfield1").value;
```

Comment: He is using the `name` attribute, not the `id` attribute.

Comment: the attribute have both the same name and id, and document.getElementByName is not a function

Comment: This is a fine way to get the value, but it is also worth suggesting an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `value` field of DOM elements:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Merry Christmas! </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> <!-- you don't have to do that, but it can help when you are to lazy using the `&...;` escapes -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="number" id="inputfield1" id="inputfield1" />
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" text="Submit" onclick="compute()" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function compute() {
                var cday = document.getElementById("inputfield1").value;
                document.write(cday);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

I used the ID here, as multiple elements can have the same name. If you want to use `name` though, replace `id="..."` with `name="..."` (as it was before) and `document.getElementById("...").value` with `document.getElementsByName("...")[0].value`.